# Is there a feature to add text on the Polyline? (Python Folium)

Tags: python, folium

I want to add text on the lines added using Polyline from within the folium library.(etc "1km" or "1ft")

```
m = folium.Map(location=[41.08468198029149, 28.8180159802915])
points = [[41.0370023, 28.9850917], [40.98186700000001, 29.0576302]]

for point in points:
    folium.Marker(point).add_to(m)

folium.PolyLine(points, color="red", weight=2.5, opacity=1).add_to(m)
```

Something like that

[image]

**[EDIT]
I find it!**

Check it out

```
line = folium.PolyLine(points, color="red", weight=2.5, opacity=1)
attr = {'fill': '#007DEF', 'font-weight': 'bold', 'font-size': '24'}
wind_textpath = plugins.PolyLineTextPath(line,
                                         "20 km",
                                         center=True,
                                         offset=7,
                                         attributes=attr)
m.add_child(line)
m.add_child(wind_textpath)
```